# How to integrate Autodesk LVM in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autodesk

I am going to build rails app which contain CAD files i want to upload that files on Autodesk(http://www.autodesk.com/) and store their URN in DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what's your question here... but if you're looking for a sample, check at https://github.com/Developer-Autodesk/sample-ruby-on-rails-app-prototyping